# Why does file system get error repeatedly even if I fsck it over and over again (on linux)?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, filesystems, fsck

My system is Gentoo Linux (kernel is 3.16.0), my file system is reiserfs.

A couple days ago, I unpacked a big tarball which is more than 100MB, and is about 1.3GB and 10,000 files after unpack , then I found several unpacked files were disordered, uncompleted, corrupt. So I did fsck on that partition (/dev/sda9). File system error was found.

```
Comparing bitmaps..vpf-10640: The on-disk and correct bitmaps differs.
2 found corruptions can be fixed when running with --fix-fixable
```

So I did fsck again with --fix-fixable, it showed me successful at last. I thought it was OK, but no.

If I unpack that tarball again, the error happened again, despite how many times I did fsck with --fix-fixable, even with --rebuild-tree.

This tarball is all right, I unpack it on another partition (reiserfs too), no error. So I doubt if there are bad blocks on disk. I use command "badblocks -nsv" to check entire disk (/dev/sda), no bad blocks is reported. (Is the way checking bad blocks right?)

I tried re-format as well, unfortunately nothing good happened. (I backed all files on the "problem" partition up to another place, and re-format that partition (still reiserfs), then copied them back. The  error appeared again after I unpacked that tarball again. I am sure that tarball is OK, because I tried other big tarballs, same error.)

So, now, I am very confusing, if there is no bad blocks on disk, why the file system gets broken over and over again after I fix it.

Comment: What filesystem are you using? There are some that get corrupted if you as much as look at them wrong...

Comment: I hate to ask, but: are you running `fsck` with the system running normally? Or are you unmounting ("umount"ing) the file system first (possibly by going into "single-user mode")?

Comment: @grawity: Reiserfs. I mentioned...

Comment: @G-Man: Of course... (You can not fsck partitions without unmounting them. Actually, I used a Live-DVD to boot my computer up and do all fsck-things, instead of my Gentoo Linux inside the hard disk. I am an experienced linux user...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have been being tortured by this problem for some weeks, I finally found the answer today.

Today, I suddenly had a flash of idea that maybe my hard disk has no problem at all, maybe it is a bug of reiserfs, a bug of my Linux kernel which is 3.16.0. So I google'd it and got the answer. Yes, it is bug of reiserfs in kernel 3.16.0 and 3.16.1.

See following links for details.
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=83321
https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=83121

So, actually this is not a common question, it is just for a specific version of linux kernel. (And if you are using the buggy version kernel with reiserfs, upgrade it as soon as possible!)

Comment: And I think it can be closed right now.